# How to use format json to get the value in Oracle

Tags: json, oracle

I am trying to get the value of LineNumber, but get error message

> ORA-31013: Invalid XPATH expression
>   31013. 00000 -  "Invalid XPATH expression"
>   *Cause:    XPATH expression passed to the function is invalid.
>   *Action:   Check the xpath expression for possible syntax errors.

It seems the *format json* doesn't work, Oracle doesn't think the *lines.x* is a json string.

```
select JSON_value(aaa.af1, '$.a.System.Publisher') 
, lines.x
, JSON_value(lines.x, '$.LineNumber')
from (
    select '{"a":{"System": {"Publisher":"dms_WarehouseExpectedReceipt"},"WarehouseCode":"WHSE1","LineItem":[{"LineNumber":1000,"ItemNumber":"P00001","PackageCode":"*","Lot":"","Gtin":"70000100000015","ExpectedDate":"2018-12-13 12:00:00","InventoryAttributes":{"Character1":"","Character2":"","Character3":""}}]}}' af1 from dual
) aaa

cross apply
  json_table(aaa.af1, '$.a.LineItem[*]' 
  COLUMNS(
     queue_child_seq for ordinality
     , x format json path '$'
  )
) lines
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. This query seems to be working perfectly fine in Oracle 18c, but throws the same error when I tested in my local ( *Oracle 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0* ).

[**LiveSQL Demo**](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/hoomxjx2rj71r20zqn8q9ci5a)

I am not completely sure about this but it appears  `JSON_value` expects the datatype to be a `CLOB` for extracted JSON strings, so the error is spcifically from `JSON_value(lines.x, '$.LineNumber')`.

The only workaround I could come up with was to cast `lines.x` explicitly to `CLOB`   using `TO_CLOB`, which worked for me in my 12.2 version.

```
JSON_value(TO_CLOB(lines.x), '$.LineNumber')
```

Comment: Thank you Kaushik Nayak. I use json_value(''||lines.x, '$.LineNumber')  as workaround. To_CLOB() is more better. It may be an Oracle bug.